# Test mock is called with correct parameters

Tags: powershell, pester-5

I have a function that uses `Invoke-RestMethod` to send data to an API. The API accepts data in different ways (Body, Header, QueryString) so the function takes in the data plus 2 parameters that determine how the data will be sent. Using a `switch` statement the data is added to the corresponding `HashTable` and then passed as a parameter to `Invoke-RestMethod`. Function code is below.

**Function**

```
function Invoke-GetRequest {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String] $Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String] $TechnicianKey,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $InputData,
        [ValidateSet("Body","Header","QueryString")]
        [String] $SendTechnicianKeyIn="Header",
        [ValidateSet("Body","QueryString")]
        [String] $SendInputDataIn="Body"
    )

    $header = @{}
    $data = @{}
    $queryString = @{}

    switch($SendTechnicianKeyIn) {
        "Body" {$data.Add('TECHNICIAN_KEY',$TechnicianKey)}
        "Header" {$header.Add('TECHNICIAN_KEY', $TechnicianKey)}
        "QueryString" {$queryString.Add('TECHNICIAN_KEY', $TechnicianKey)}
    }

    switch($SendInputDataIn) {
        "Body" {$data.Add('input_data', $InputData)}
        "QueryString" {$queryString.Add('input_data', $InputData)}
    }

    if($queryString.Count -gt 0) {
        $uri = Format-HttpQueryString -Uri $Url -QueryParameter $queryString
    }
    else {
        $uri = $Url
    }

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $header -Body $data -ErrorAction Stop
    $response
}
```

I am writing unit tests using Pester so have mocked `Invoke-RestMethod` and I need to verify that the data is being added to the correct `HashTable` and is therefore `Invoke-RestMethod` is called with the correct parameters.

I have not found a way to directly test the `HashTable`s so the only way I can think to do this is to use a `ParameterFilter` on the `Mock` so that it is only called if the filter matches but if I do that and the filter doesn't match then a call goes out to the real `Invoke-RestMethod` which obviously is not wanted in a unit test. Below is an example of the `Pester` test.

**Pester Test**

```
Context 'Valid Calls' {

    BeforeAll {
        $splat = @{
            Url = 'https://www.test.com/api/'
            TechnicianKey = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
            InputData = '{"list_info":{"row_count":"10"}}'
        }
    }
        
    Describe 'TechnicianKey Header, InputData Body Default' {
            
        BeforeAll {
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq $splat.Url -and $header.TECHNICIAN_KEY -eq $splat.TechnicianKey -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData }} {}
        }

        It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
            Invoke-GetRequest @splat
            Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try $header = [pscustomobject]@{}

Comment: It’s been a while since I used Pester, but I seem to remember doing something similar with multiple mocks - one used the parameter filter to match the expected values, and a second with no parameter filter to catch any unmatched calls - the latter just threw an exception to break the test. It was a while ago though so I might be remembering how I *wished* it worked at the time, rather than how it actually does :-).

Answer (score 0):

Posting my final solution for future reference. I used the `ParameterFilter` with the different values for the `Uri`, `Headers` and `Body` so that an error would be thrown if the `Mock` never fired. This still doesn't fully solve the problem though because say I was refactoring/updating this code in the future and I make a change so that the filter no longer matches, then this is going to make a real call to `Invoke-RestMethod`.

```
Describe 'Unit: Invoke-GetRequest' -Tag Unit {

    Context 'Valid Calls' {

        BeforeAll {
            $splat = @{
                Url = 'https://test.com/api/'
                TechnicianKey = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                InputData = '{"list_info":{"row_count":"10"}}'
                SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'Header'
                SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq $splat.Url -and $data.TECHNICIAN_KEY -eq $splat.TechnicianKey -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData } {}
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq 'https://test.com/api/?TECHNICIAN_KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData } {}
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq 'https://test.com/api/?input_data={"list_info":{"row_count":"10"}}' -and $data.TECHNICIAN_KEY -eq $splat.TechnicianKey } {}
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq $splat.Url -and $header.TECHNICIAN_KEY -eq $splat.TechnicianKey -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData } {}              
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq 'https://test.com/api/?TECHNICIAN_KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData } {}
            Mock Invoke-RestMethod -ParameterFilter { $uri -eq $splat.Url -and $header.TECHNICIAN_KEY -eq $splat.TechnicianKey -and $data.input_data -eq $splat.InputData } {}
        }
        
        Describe 'TechnicianKey Body, InputData Body' {

            BeforeAll {
                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'Body'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }
        
        Describe 'TechnicianKey QueryString, InputData Body' {

            BeforeAll {

                Mock Format-HttpQueryString {
                    'https://test.com/api/?TECHNICIAN_KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                }

                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'QueryString'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod and Format-HttpQueryString once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Format-HttpQueryString -Times 1 -Exactly
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
                
            }
        }

        Describe 'TechnicianKey Body, InputData QueryString' {

            BeforeAll {
                
                Mock Format-HttpQueryString {
                    'https://test.com/api/?input_data={"list_info":{"row_count":"10"}}'
                }

                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'Body'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'QueryString'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod and Format-HttpQueryString once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Format-HttpQueryString -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }

        Describe 'TechnicianKey Header, InputData Body' {

            BeforeAll {
                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'Header'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }

        Describe 'TechnicianKey QueryString, InputData Body' {

            BeforeAll {

                Mock Format-HttpQueryString {
                    'https://test.com/api/?TECHNICIAN_KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                }

                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'QueryString'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Format-HttpQueryString -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }

        Describe 'TechnicianKey Header, InputData Body Explicit' {

            BeforeAll {
                $splat.SendTechnicianKeyIn = 'Header'
                $splat.SendInputDataIn = 'Body'
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }

        Describe 'TechnicianKey Header, InputData Body Default' {
        
            BeforeAll {

                $splat.Remove('SendTechnicianKeyIn')
                $splat.Remove('SendInputDataIn')
            }

            It 'Should invoke Invoke-RestMethod once' {
                Invoke-GetRequest @splat
                Should -Invoke -CommandName Invoke-RestMethod -Times 1 -Exactly
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can add a second mock *without* any filters that acts as a fallback,  and then just throw an exception inside the body - that way if your code calls the cmdlet with parameters other than the ones that match the filtered version of the mock your test will fail because it will call the fallback instead. I can’t remember if the definition order affects which is invoked so you might have to experiment…

Comment: Thanks @mclayton. Will see if that works. I would hope it would look for a `ParameterFilter` first and then without it would be a catch all, but will soon find out!